# Avoid/disable some specific rows from sorting process using jQuery tablesorter.js

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have one table which I am sorting using jquery plugin tablesorter. 
Here i want to avoid first row {class="avoid-sort" } to be sort   when any column is selected  for sorting.
example:

---

```
       <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="header">#</th>
            <th class="header">Purchase Date</th>
            <th class="header">Course Name</th>
            <th class="header">Amount(in $)</th>
            <th class="header">User Name</th>
            <th class="header">Share</th>
            <th class="header">Net Revenue [$236.41]</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
  <tbody>

       <tr class="avoid-sort">
            <th colspan="7">Total Revenue</th>
            <td>236.41</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>January 3rd, 2013</td>
                <td>Tackle Certification</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>Khushi Jha</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>33.69</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>January 3rd, 2013</td>
                <td>Flag Certification</td>
                <td>100</td> 
                <td>Pay</td>
                <td>70</td>
                 <td>67.67</td>
      </tr>
                            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>January 3rd, 2013</td>
                <td>Tackle Certification</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <!--                    <td>-->
                    <!--</td>-->
                <td>Pay</td>
                <td>35</td>
                 <td>33.69</td>

   </tr>
```

---

tr class="avoid-sort" should not come in sorting!

Please help!!

Comment: can't you use jQuery `:not()` ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. If you are using the original tablesorter, you can get this [static row widget](https://github.com/ascii-soup/Tablesorter-Static-Row-Plugin) to "lock" the row in place.
2. If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/), you can just add a non-sortable tbody, like this ([demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-multiple-tbodies.html)):

   ```
   <table>
   <thead>
     ...
   </thead>

   <!-- rows within this tbody are ignored -->
   <tbody class="avoid-sort">
     <tr>
       <th colspan="7">Total Revenue</th>
       <td>236.41</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>

   <tbody>
     <!-- sortable rows -->
     <tr>
       ...
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

   then initialize the table like this:

   ```
   $(function() { 

     $("table").tablesorter({ 
       theme : 'blue', 
       cssInfoBlock : "avoid-sort", 
       widgets: [ 'zebra' ] 
     }); 

   });
   ```

Comment: Top stuff, I had this problem and cssInfoBlock fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! My fork also as a version of the [static row widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-static-row.html).

Answer (score 2):

In [Mottie's fork](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter) the [*staticRow* plugin is now built-in](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-static-row.html):

```html
<script src="/js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/tablesorter/widgets/widget-staticRow.min.js"></script>
<!-- … -->
<tr class="static">…</tr>
```

```js
$("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: ['staticRow']
})
```

Alternatively, you can set a custom class name:

```html
<tr class="tablesorter-static">…</tr>
```

```js
$("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: ['staticRow'],
    widgetOptions: {
        // Note it expects a CSS selector, not a raw class name
        staticRow_class: ".tablesorter-static"
    }
})
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$(function() {     
$("#myTable").tablesorter({
        headers: {4: {sorter: false},8: {sorter: false}}
    });
});
```

here 4,8 are column numbers. column starts with 0

Comment: This is not what asked in the question. Your answer will disable sorting for columns with index 4 and 8. The question asked wants to ignore sorting certain rows, not columns. @ABDUL JAMAL